# Method does not override method from its superclass

Tags: java, android

Sou novato no Java e estou aprendendo app para Android e no meu percurso, esbarrei nesse erro:

```
Method does not override method from its superclass
```

A palavra @Override fica sublinhado em vermelho, mas não consegui entender o erro. Segue abaixo o código:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trata-se de um erro de grafia.

Substitua `OnCreate()` por [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)), que é o nome correto do método que você está tentando sobrescrever.

Comment: Perfeito Diego. Muito Obrigado.